# Unity scene transition effect with AssetBundleManager.LoadLevelAsync()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prime31

I know there is a scene transition effect between scene for normal scene load from `SceneManager`, but how about assets bundle scene load ?

This is example of scene transition for normal scene load. 
https://github.com/prime31/TransitionKit

But I can't find anything that related to assets bundle scene transition. I try to modified the code but it does not work since I don't really understand assets bundles structure.